# Bicycle module in veins 5.2

Tags: omnet++, veins

From the Veins documentation: [Link](https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#veins_inet)
I see that there are other modules other than Car, such as bike, bicycle, train...

In veins, however, I cannot find these other modules.
In fact, in the directory /src/veins/nodes there is only Car.ned as the vehicle node.

My question is: are these modules available? I am interested in the bicycle module.
If not, what is the best way to recreate it? Thank you.